# how to get itemId values using hasOwnProperty method to hide a tab in ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I tried this code to hide a tab:

```
hideTab: function() {
    var dashboard_obj = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('sellax-navigation-panel');
    var tabBarObj = dashboard_obj[0].down('tabpanel').getTabBar();
    var tabsArray = tabBarObj.items;
    for(var tabBarObjItems = 0; tabBarObjItems < tabsArray.length; tabBarObjItems++)
    {
        var tabObj = tabsArray.get(tabBarObjItems);
        if(tabObj.card.id == "tabSettings")
        {
            var tabObj_list = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('sellax-navigation-sub[id=settingsSubNav]');
            var tabBarObj_list = tabObj_list[0].getTabBar();
            var tabsArray_list = tabBarObj_list.items;
            for(var tabSubBarObjItems = 0; tabSubBarObjItems < tabsArray_list.length; tabSubBarObjItems++)
            {
                if(tabsArray_list_item.id == "tab-1334")
                {
                    tabsArray_list_item.hide();
                }
```

But the console values are not correct, so how can I hide that tab?

My code:

```
var tabsArray_list = tabBarObj_list.items;
for(var tabSubBarObjItems = 0; tabSubBarObjItems < tabsArray_list.length; tabSubBarObjItems++)
{   
    var tabsArray_list_item = tabsArray_list.get(tabSubBarObjItems);
    if (tabsArray_list_item.hasOwnProperty('itemId'))
    {
        value = tabsArray_list_item['itemId'];
        if (value == 'tabdeptsList')
        {
            tabsArray_list_item.hide();
        }
    }
```

Code throws no error but tab is not hiding.

How to get ItemId of this panel and hide this tab?

Answer (score 0):

### Find Component in Container

To retrieve the component for a specific `itemId` you should use the `getComponent` method of the `Ext.container.Container`. It accepts an itemId as it's parameter and returns the matching component.

From the [Sencha ExtJs 6.2.1 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.container.Container.html?#method-getComponent):

> Examines this container's items property and gets a direct child component of this container.

So you do not need too loop over the items, just call the function.

```
var tabsArray_list = tabBarObj_list.getComponent('tabdeptsList');
```

### Hide Tab

To hide the associated tab, you can use the `tab` property of the component.

```
var tab = tabsArray_list.tab; // Each component has a reference to it's tab
tab.hide();
```

### Full Code

```
var tabsArray_list = tabBarObj_list.getComponent('tabdeptsList');
var tab = tabsArray_list.tab;
tab.hide();
```